# I am having issues handling a couple deprecation warnings in v2.1.0

Tags: ember.js, deprecated

I can not figure out how to handle these deprecation warnings:
[image]

[image]

Here is my serializer:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: '_id'
});
```

Comment: What version of Ember Data are you using? 1.13?

Comment: "ember-data": "1.13.7"

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to specify `isNewSerializerAPI: true` in your serializer, like shown in http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html#toc_opt-into-the-new-serializer-api.